# Get the full word(s) by knowing only just a part of it

Tags: python, string, text

I am searching through a text file line by line and i want to get back all strings that contains the prefix **AAAXX1234**. For example in my text file i have these lines

> Hello my ID is [123423819::**AAAXX1234_3412**] #I want that(AAAXX1234_3412)
>
> Hello my ID is [738281937::**AAAXX1234_3413**:**AAAXX1234_4212**] #I
>   want both of them(AAAXX1234_3413, AAAXX1234_4212)
>
> Hello my ID is [123423819::XXWWF1234_3098] #I don't care about that

The code i have a just to check if the line starts with "Hello my ID is"

```
with open(file_hrd,'r',encoding='utf-8') as hrd:
    hrd=hrd.readlines()
    for line in hrd:
        if line.startswith("Hello my ID is"):
            #do something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

with open(file_hrd,'r',encoding='utf-8') as hrd:
    res = []
    for line in hrd:
        res += re.findall('AAAXX1234_\d+', line)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['AAAXX1234_3412', 'AAAXX1234_3413', 'AAAXX1234_4212']
```

Comment: Note that this will also find ids in the part after the `#` which appears to be some kind of message text.

Comment: @poke i think he just added that for clarification

Comment: Oh, you’re probably right! I didn’t realize that – sorry!

Comment: Thank you all for your time!I got this as correct because it seems to be the simpler for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I’d suggest you to *parse* your lines and extract the information into meaningful parts. That way, you can then use a simple `startswith` on the ID part of your line. In addition, this will also let you control where you find these prefixes, e.g. in case the lines contains additional data that could also theoretically contain something that looks like an ID.

Something like this:

```
if line.startswith('Hello my ID is '):
    idx_start = line.index('[')
    idx_end = line.index(']', idx_start)
    idx_separator = line.index(':', idx_start, idx_end)

    num = line[idx_start + 1:idx_separator]
    ids = line[idx_separator + 2:idx_end].split(':')

    print(num, ids)
```

This would give you the following output for your three example lines:

```
123423819 ['AAAXX1234_3412']
738281937 ['AAAXX1234_3413', 'AAAXX1234_4212']
123423819 ['XXWWF1234_3098']
```

With that information, you can then check the ids for a prefix:

```
if any(ids, lambda x: x.startswith('AAAXX1234')):
    print('do something')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions through the `re` module and its `findall()` function should be enough:

```
import re


with open('file.txt') as file:
    prefix = 'AAAXX1234'
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    output = list()
    for line in lines:
        output.extend(re.findall(f'{prefix}_[\d]+', line))
```

Comment: Note that this will also find ids in the part after the `#` which appears to be some kind of message text.

Comment: Oh, yes. I thought those comments were only for illustrative purposes in the OP's example.

Comment: Oh! That’s a very fair interpretation; I didn’t realize that this might be the case!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, tho. I'll wait for OP's clarification to update my answer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by findall with the regex `r'AAAXX1234_[0-9]+'`, it will find all parts of the string that start with `AAAXX1234_` and then grabs all of the numbers after it, change `+` to `*` if you want it to match 'AAAXX1234_' on it's own as well